# Why offline first not working in polymer2

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-2.x

I cannot convinced why offline first not working in Polymer2. Here is my `sw-precache-config.js` and `polymer.json`

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    '/index.html',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js',
    '/images/*'
  ],
  navigateFallback: '/index.html',
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!.*\.html$|\/data\/).*/],
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /\/bower_components\/webcomponentsjs\/.*.js/,
      handler: 'fastest',
      options: {
        cache: {
          name: 'webcomponentsjs-polyfills-cache'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /\/data\/images\/.*/,
      handler: 'cacheFirst',
      options: {
        cache: {
          maxEntries: 200,
          name: 'items-cache'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /\/data\/.*json/,
      handler: 'fastest',
      options: {
        cache: {
          maxEntries: 100,
          name: 'data-cache'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

polymer.json

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/my-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/my-home.html",
    "src/my-category.html",
    "src/my-company.html",
    "src/my-courses.html",
    "src/my-view404.html"
  ],
  "sources": [
    "src/**/*",
    "data/**/*",
    "images/**/*",
    "bower.json"
  ],
  "extraDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*.js"
  ],
  "lint": {
    "rules": ["polymer-2"]
  },
  "builds": [{
    "name": "bundled",
    "addServiceWorker": true,
    "bundle": true,
    "js": {"minify": false, "compile": false},
    "css": {"minify": false},
    "html": {"minify": false}
  },{
    "name": "unbundled",
    "addServiceWorker": true,
    "bundle": false,
    "js": {"minify": true, "compile": true},
    "css": {"minify": true},
    "html": {"minify": true}
  }]
}
```

Please let me know why it's not working at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Be specific.

Comment: Why I off wifi or internet, it gone `page cannot be displayed` instead of displaying cache instead. https://13-dot-courses-polymer-166507.appspot.com/

Comment: Is that a link to your app? It doesn't look like a service-worker is being loaded and run. [These](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/index.html#L90-L94) are the lines in the starter kit that load the service worker if the browser supports it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `"swPrecacheConfig": "sw-precache-config.js",` to each `'build'` array item you want to include your service-worker.
Also, note that the dev (`polymer serve`) environment (not builded) bypass the service worker registration.